# How do I enable cross-object referencing?

Tags: cross-object

In an Account custom field formula I'm trying to reference a Contact custom field. I recall when writing these formulas from a previous company that a simple Contact.fieldname__c would suffice to reference that field, but when I enter the formula right now it's giving me a "Error: Field Contact does not exist. Check spelling."

Do I need to enable a setting, or am I doing something wrong?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You **cannot** refer a Contact field on Account as there's no reference of Contact on the Account but the other way round. You can build a [cross-object formula](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=customize_cross_object.htm&type=5) only on detail of a master-detail and between objects which are related to each other through lookup fields.

> Cross-object formulas can reference merge fields from a master (“parent”) object if an object is on the detail side of a master-detail relationship. Cross-object formulas also work with lookup relationships.

Comment: Is there then an elegant way for me to say something like: If the contact has an email address, then the Account checkbox custom field should be checked? Or should I try to take a different structure?

Comment: Because an Account to Contact is a 1:Many relationship, so if you have a checkbox on Account to identify if "the" Contact has an email address, you need to determine, which Contact that would be.